# hide toolbar at bottom of UiWebView when scrolling down

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have the following code that successfully hides the bottom toolbar when NOT at the top of the web view as shown in attached images. (below)

What I am trying to do is hide the toolbar completely and then expand the web view to take up the extra space (similar to how Safari does this). Any help would be great!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.url != nil)
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[StoreWebViewController checkAndPrependProtocolForUrl:self.url]]]];
        self.webView.delegate = self;
    }

    for (id subview in self.webView.subviews)
    {
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        {
            UIScrollView * s = (UIScrollView*)subview;
            originalDelegate = s.delegate;
            s.delegate = self;
            break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll :(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) //Show toolbar when at top
    {
        [self.toolbar setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.toolbar setHidden:YES];
    }
    [originalDelegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
```

[image: Show toolbar]

[image: Hide toolbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made this in an app, using text area, so i think its the same by replacing textView with webView.

**Initialize directions & flags**

```
@implementation YourViewController{
    BOOL tap;
    BOOL hideNav;
    BOOL mustShowNav;
}

@synthesize webView;

typedef enum ScrollDirection {
    ScrollDirectionNone,
    ScrollDirectionRight,
    ScrollDirectionLeft,
    ScrollDirectionUp,
    ScrollDirectionDown,
} ScrollDirection;
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    webView.delegate = self;
    hideNav = NO;
    mustShowNav = NO;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(webViewTapped:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

**The scroll**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    ScrollDirection scrollDirection;

    if (lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionDown;
    else
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionUp;


    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionDown && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 50 && !mustShowNav) {
        hideNav = YES;
        tap = 0;
    } else {
        hideNav = NO;
    }

    if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionUp && mustShowNav){
        hideNav = NO;
        mustShowNav = NO;
    }

    if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionDown && endScrolling > scrollView.contentSize.height - 50 && !mustShowNav) {
        mustShowNav = YES;
    }

    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:hideNav animated:YES];
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    [originalDelegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
```

**The tap gesture**

```
- (void)webViewTapped:(id)sender
{
    if(!tap){
        hideNav = NO;
        tap = 1;
    } else {
        hideNav = YES;
        tap = 0;
    }
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:hideNav animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I had to move lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset to the end for some reason (Not sure WHY) and I had to add some delegate implementation. Maybe you could shed some light on why moving lastContentOffset to the end makes a difference. (I don't see why it should as it is just a variable)

Comment: It seems to be because of [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:hideNav animated:YES]. It must change the offset values...Please confirm this is why

Comment: Its sounds weird, but maybe you are right. I'll see it in my app, and update you.

Comment: I think its exactly the same, i haven't notice any difference, although i made several tests. As you said, its just a variable, so  when this modified, the new value will be used in the next call of `scrollViewDidScroll`. Of course might have a minor different behaviour because of `setToolbarHidden` but not such as to disturb the user.

Comment: It makes a difference in my app where the toolbar never hides.

Comment: (well it hides for a split second then shows up again). If you want I can email you the full source so you can try)

Comment: You can try it at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwda153owhu6quh/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-iOS-scroll_temp.zip

Simply enter a url that has a lot of scrolling and then try it. The scrolling code is in StoreWebViewController.m. Maybe something else is causing it. (NOTE: There are still UI bugs in the program as I just started it). IT only works on iPhone currently (not iPad)

Comment: You are right, if i move the lastContentOffset on top, it hides for a sec and then shows up again. The funny thing with this, is that it doesn't happen in my app, although it has the same code.

Comment: is your app for iOS 7?

Comment: I ended up not being able to use this code as it really hampered the performance of UiwebView. I am on a 4s

Comment: For performance reasons, try `scrollStarts`, `scrollAtMiddle`, `scrollAtEnding` and `endOfScroll` functions instead, with the same implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to let your Javascript trigger those events and the hosting view controller should handle them.