# How to hide UINavigationbar when i pull-down the TableView in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController object, there is a UITableView object in it. I'd like to hide the UINavigationbar when I pull-down the UITableViewCell, and display the UINavigationbar when I pull-up the UITableViewCell. What should I do? thanks.

Comment: This is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999839/hide-toolbar-at-bottom-of-uiwebview-when-scrolling-down/22000609#22000609, only replace this `[[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:hideNav animated:YES];` with `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hideNav animated:YES];` and the `webView` with `tableView` and you are done.

Comment: thank u for your help,Now I used like this:
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    if (velocity.y > 0)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method. Check the current shown/hidden state and the `contentOffset` position (compared to the previous position) to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks dimimpou and Wain.
Now I used your idea like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    if (velocity.y > 0)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```